# "Running transaction (shutdown inhibited)" how much "inhibited" is shutdown?

Tags: fedora, yum

When installing some packages with `yum` I see the text:

> Running transaction (shutdown inhibited)

What does it exactly mean? Would it prevent me from shutting down the system if I typed `shutdown -h now` in another terminal? That is, what kind of "inhibitions" does it prompt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a feature of systemd 183 and newer, documented most fully in the [Inhibitor Lock Developer Documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/). You can also look at the man page for `systemd-inhibit` — and for that matter, you can use that command to run another command with an inhibitor taken.

The things that can be inhibited include:

- shutdown
- sleep
- idle
- plus handle-power-key, handle-suspend-key, handle-hibernate-key, handle-lid-switch

You can see the currently-held inhibitors with `systemd-inhibit --list`, and for example on my system I see

```
 Who: mattdm (UID 18281/mattdm, PID 4207/gnome-settings-)
What: handle-lid-switch
 Why: Multiple displays attached
Mode: block
```

among others.

When applying updates, Yum (and now DNF, and as I recall actually RPM itself via a default plugin) takes out a `block` inhibitor against `idle` and `shutdown` (but not `sleep`), to keep you from accidentally powering off your machine mid-transaction and potentially messing up the system (with a package halfway overwriting an older one).

This can, however, be overridden using the `-i` (or `--ignore-inhibitors`) option for `systemctl` (usually with `poweroff` or `reboot` in this case).

I'm not actually sure what happens if `shutdown` is used to power off or reboot at a given time and an inhibitor is active when the time expires.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thanks a lot for pointing to the man page, detailing the options, showing an example and providing a great explanation!

Comment: I did test it: while installing some stuff I opened another console and said "shutdown -h now". The message I got is: `Operation inhibited by "yum cli" (PID 16003 "yum", user root), reason is "Running transaction". // Please retry operation after closing inhibitors and logging out other users. // Alternatively, ignore inhibitors and users with 'systemctl poweroff -i'.` Cool!

Comment: @fedorqui Hmmm, I think there's an RFE that needs to be filed, because I'd hate for `shutdown -r +60` to fail when no one is around...

Comment: I guess RFE is a bug report, haven't heard it before. Also, not sure why this is a problem, looks like the way to have the shutdown inhibited to me.

Comment: @fedorqui "Request for Enhancement" — an issue filed for something which isn't a bug but where additional functionality would be nice. In this case, an  `-i` flag to shutdown which lets it ignore inhibitors even at a later time. Or even an option to wait until the inhibitor is lifted and _then_ shutdown.